# C socket - consecutive read/write, what happens?

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

In a server/client in C, TCP, what happens if I do consecutive read/write in my program? Is this possibile, or do I've always to follow the structure "client write->server read->server write->client read"?

Is it possible to do something like this? Or is it possible that data from the 3rd write in the server are received from the 2nd read in the client, and other bad things like this?

client.c

```
write (1)
read (2)
read (3)
read (4)
```

server.c

```
read (1)
write (2)
write (3)
write (4)
```

Comment: It's not a bad thing - it's what happens with octet, (byte), streams.  There are no 'packets' at user-level.  No 'messages' longer than one byte.  What you seem to be describing in normal behaviour for TCP.

Comment: @MartinJames maybe that my explaination hasn't been good, what I meant is that if the write (3) is received from the read (2), it's a bad thing because data from wirte (3) will be read by read (2), which is an undesider behaviour. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. reads will block (by default) until data are available to read on the socket. There's no need to try to arrange for reads and writes in a particular order, your program will just wait until there is something to read before the `read()` call returns.

Your code will result in this:

```
Server blocks in read()
Client write()s
Client blocks in read()
Server receives data, read() returns
Server write()s three times
Client receives data, read(1) returns
Client's read(2) is called and returns as soon as data arrive
Client's read(3) is called and returns as soon as data arrive
```

On a really fast link it's possible that the server write()s and the client read()s happen at roughly the same time, maybe even interleaved, but the server write()s will always be in order and the client's read()s will always be in order.

Data ordering is preserved if the sockets are SOCK_STREAM, eg. TCP or UNIX sockets like you're asking about.

So read(2) will always return the data written in write(2) for a TCP socket.

If you used a UDP socket (SOCK_DGRAM's default) you might find that the messages are received out-of-order or not at all.

Comment: ... if blocking sockets are used.

Comment: Sockets block by default, at least for POSIX/Unix sockets.

Comment: if the write (3) is received from the read (2), it's a bad thing because data from wirte (3) will be read by read (2), which is an undesidered behaviour. Is this possible? Or the blocking makes it impossible that this happens?

Comment: That will not happen with a TCP socket. A TCP socket will preserve ordering which is what you expect. If you used a UDP socket you might see the out-of-order delivery you're concerned about. With TCP, read(2) will always return the data written in write(2).

Answer (score 4):

TCP transfers a data stream.

So N calls to `write` could result in M calls to `read` (with N>0 and M>0 and N<=number of bytes transferred and M<=number of bytes transferred).

The order in which the bytes were send will however be preserved between the various writes and reads involved.

As a direct consequence to this you cannot just use the plain number of calls to `write` and `read` to synchronise processes. You need to add for example the number of bytes to be transferred by each step.

To cut it short: You need an application level protocol on top of the TCP stream.

Comment: Mmm, so what I wrote in the comment of the question, is possible or not? "if the write (3) is received from the read (2), it's a bad thing because data from wirte (3) will be read by read (2), which is an undesidered behaviour. Is this possible?"

Comment: You cannot just use the plain number of calls to `write` and `read` so synchonise your processes. You need to add the number of bytes to be transferred by each step.

Comment: Yes I know, I used a plain number to explain the situation on here. What I wanted to know if the order of write/read will be preserver, and you replied in your answer. Thank you so much!